# How do I make a wide PanoramaItem always align to left when swiping back?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, panorama-control

So I created a bunch of PanoramaItems with Width of 600 and Orientation of Horizontal.  When I swipe to the right direction the items align perfect on each item.  When I swipe back to the left direction, it appears everything is aligned to the right side forcing me to swipe again to get my alignment correctly.

Is there a way to set the focus location of a panoranaItem each time someone changes their selection?  Because it is odd to swipe once in one direction and swipe twice in the other.